# dealing with arrays containing temperature of the year

Tags: java, arrays

i have an array of length 360 this array holds the temperature of every day in the year I am asked to write a method which calculate and prints the average of temperature in each month taking into consideration that each month is made of 30 days. this is my code till naw

```
public static void displayAvgTemp(int[] temp){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(i / 30 != 0){
            for(int j = i; i < temp.length; i++)
                sum += temp[i]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not every day? 360? Oh nvm, 30 days per month.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a reason for the `i / 30 != 0` check?  You don't want to include the temperature from the first of each month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void displayAvgTemp(int[] temp) {
    //its a problem that temp[] starts from index 0
    //so I shift elements with 1 to right, so I can iterate starting from index 1
    int[] tempShifted = new int[temp.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, tempShifted, 1, temp.length);
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < tempShifted.length; i++) {
        sum += tempShifted[i];
        if (i % 30 == 0) {
            System.out.println(sum / 30);
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An integer division might not be ideal, for an average temperature.

Comment: but why the average temp of month one is always being zero

Comment: because there was an error in the code, the "|| i == 0" was missing, so try now

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, this adds up 30 temperatures in January, but 29 temperatures every subsequent month.  But because it always divides by 30, the averages are ALL incorrect, except the first one.  I am tempted to downvote, but I don't know the reason why Sara wanted to exclude cases where `i / 30 == 0` (I did ask, under the question).  I strongly feel though, that this answer is NOT what Sara needs.

Comment: You are right again @DavidWallace, I edited the code again, If you have a better idea how to fix it, please edit it.

Comment: It does look much better now, although I'm not sure why you're starting with an `arraycopy`.  Whether it's what Sara actually needs is impossible to tell, though, because she still hasn't answered the question about what the `i / 30 != 0` check is for.  Maybe she had some specific reason for wanting to exclude those temperatures, or maybe it was just a mistake.

Comment: I use arraycopy to shift elements with one to right, so I can iterate starting from index 1